# Language is not changing in AlertDialog when changing English to Arabic

Tags: android, android-context

I am working on a application in which I have to change apps content from English to Arabic and vice versa.
Language is being changed according to language selection in Activities and Fragments but sometimes its doesn't change in `AlertDialog`. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Below are the details.

**Class & Method to show dialog**

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
public static void showAlertDialog(Context ctx, String message) {
    if (ctx == null) {
        return;
    }
    showAlertDialog(ctx, message, Gravity.CENTER);
}

public static void showAlertDialog(Context ctx, String message, int gravity) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated
                        // method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(gravity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

    }

}
}
```

**Method which is calling above method**

```
    @Override
public void showAlert(String message) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(MerchantLoginActivity.this, message);
    }
}
```

**Method being used in every activity to change content's language**

```
   @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    Locale languageType = LanguageUtil.getLanguageType(newBase);
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, languageType));
}
```

**Button click event on which language is being changed | MainActivity**

```
@OnClick(R.id.language_button)
void onLanguageClicked(View view) {

    // Getting saved language


    currentLanguage = LocaleHelper.getLanguage(getBaseContext());
    String languageToLoad = (currentLanguage.equals(Language.ARABIC) ? Language.ENGLISH : Language.ARABIC); // your language

   Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    LocaleHelper.setLocale(getApplicationContext(), languageToLoad);
    //LanguageUtil.changeLanguageType(getApplicationContext(), locale);
    FlooosyApplication.getInstance().setLanguage(languageToLoad);
    this.recreate();
    //onRestart();
}
```

**onRestart() | MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    if (locale.equals(Language.ARABIC))
        locale = Language.ENGLISH;
    else
        locale = Language.ARABIC;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is not to put language select in your app.  The OS has a language select.  Respect that.  Doing anything else is a never ending fight because the OS will always tell your app to use the one selected in the OS settings.  Either that or COMPLETELY abandon all Android R.string usage and roll your own.  Anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you @GabeSechan. I agree with you, but I will have to do it because my client wants to see it in his application.

Comment: Then I'd completely drop Android's string functionality and replace it.  It's about the only way you'll get something that works all of the time.  Depending on the language you may need to anyway-  I don't know Arabic, but I know Hebrew and other languages in the area have gender specific forms of words-  Android's system doesn't support that.

Comment: You means after checking the selected language I have to set particular string without using string.xml file?

Comment: Yeah.  You can try and avoid it, but I think it will just be a long series of corner cases like this.  Plus there's the question of translation quality, the Android system is limited in terms of conjugating for different language forms (it really only supports plurality).

Comment: Ok. I will do this because, now this is the only way i can do it, as you suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes i also haveing same problem AlertDialog not loading second language (if you close app completly using optionmenu)

Answer (score 0):

By first start of app your language is **default**

You check always for **Arabic** and thats for begin is always **false**.
By click on Button it will be set to **Arabic**, and by second click to **Englich**

**onRestart()** contains current selected language. change to

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    if (locale.equals(Language.ARABIC))
        locale = Language.ARABIC;
    else
        locale = Language.ENGLISH;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: yea, how Gabe said, its because you depend on strings xml file, what is not seeing in your examples. In other case, this would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().isEmpty()) {
            setLocal("en");
        } else {
            setLocal(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Notic :</font>"))
                .setMessage(R.string.sure)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}




private void setLocal(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadLocale() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "");
    setLocal(language);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are a bit unwelcome. If you add some text with the intention of your code you will help everybody who tries to understand if this code is a suitable solution.